# bootstrap: hidden-print without css

Tags: html, css

I have the following code which can be found here: [https://codepen.io/aaron_1986/pen/oBJOyK].

I have to rewrite the html code using bootstrap (hidden-print), I *cannot* touch the css code at all. All I have to do is style the page for print-out... on print view - there is no h1 size text and only basic [text] style links.

Could someone please explain or help me through the process?

html:

```
<header>
   <h1 class="hidden-lg-up">Only show this on print screen</h1>
   <h1 class="hidden-md-down hidden-print">show this on medium size and up</h1>

  <nav>
     <a href="http://www.example.com/">link to homepage</a>
     <a href="http://www.example.com/">other link</a>
  </nav>
```

css:

```
header {
   background-color:#0066FF;
   padding: 1%;
   margin: 1%;
}

header h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    color:rgba(0,0,0,.7);;

}

nav a {
    display:block;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 2%;
    margin: 1%;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color:rgba(255,0,0,.7);
}
```

[Print out image -  not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0CrW.png)

Comment: What is your desired output? Your code **already** uses Bootstrap's `hidden-print` class. Did you remember to include the Bootstrap library?

Comment: My output is for plain text and links - yes all bootstrap libraries are included.

Comment: If I look at your codepen and then choose "Print Preview" it looks like it's working as designed. The pen shows "show this on medium size and up" in a large font, and "Only show this on print screen" during the print preview. So maybe your CSS is not loading properly. Try clearing the cache and reloading, or using another browser.

Comment: I have uploaded a new image which is showing the print-out view. I need to remove the h1 header text (and replace it with smaller size text), moreover, I also need to remove the borders around the links.